# Facebook apps does not accept custom domains

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0

I try to use OAuth for Facebook on **custom domain extensions** like https://any.company/ or https://they.network/ that are valid real domains.

On settings page, in the AppDomains I get an error message:

> App domains must match the domain of the Facebook Web Games URL
>   (https), Mobile Site URL, Unity Binary URL, Site URL or Secure Page
>   Tab URL. Please correct these domains: they.network

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for telling us

Comment: Actually I will delete this post. I was trying to set tha custom extension in the general settings App Domains instead of login settings Add Domains